# Can vtk InsertValue take float arguments?

Tags: python, vtk

I have a question about InsertValue

If I understand it only takes integer arguements. I was wondering if there is a way to have it take float values? Or maybe some other function that does the job of InsertValue but takes float values? I know there is InsertNextValue, but I am not sure if it'll be efficient in my case since my array is a very big array (~ 100.000 by 120)

Below is my code and in my code I am making the entries of `fl` values integers to make it work for now but ideally it'll be great if I don't have to do that.

Thanks in advance :)

```
 import vtk
 import math
 from vtk import vtkStructuredGrid, vtkPoints, vtkFloatArray, vtkXMLStructuredGridWriter
 import scipy.io
 import numpy
 import os

 #loading the matlab files
 mats = scipy.io.loadmat('/home/lusine/data/3DDA/donut_for_vtk/20130228_050000_3D_E=1.mat')

#x,y,z coordinate, fl flux values
xx = mats['xvect']
yy = mats['yvect']
zz = mats['zvect']
fl = mats['fluxmesh3d'] #3d matrix

nx = xx.shape[1]
ny = yy.shape[1]
nz = zz.shape[1]

fl = numpy.nan_to_num(fl)
inx = numpy.nonzero(fl)
l = len(inx[1])

grid = vtk.vtkStructuredGrid() 
grid.SetDimensions(nx,ny,nz) # sets the dimensions of the grid 
pts = vtk.vtkPoints() # represents 3D points, The data model for vtkPoints is an array of vx-vy-vz triplets accessible by (point or cell) id.
pts.SetNumberOfPoints(nx*ny*nz) # Specify the number of points for this object to hold.

p=0
for i in range(l):
      pts.InsertPoint(p, xx[0][inx[0][i]], yy[0][inx[1][i]], zz[0][inx[2][i]])
      p = p + 1 

SetPoint()
grid.SetPoints(pts)

cdata = vtk.vtkFloatArray()
cdata.SetNumberOfComponents(1)

cdata.SetNumberOfTuples((nx-1)*(ny-1)*(nz-1))
cdata.SetName('cellData')

p=0
for i in range(l-1):
    cdata.InsertValue(p,inx[0][i]+inx[1][i]+inx[2][i])
p = p+1


grid.GetCellData().SetScalars(cdata)


pdata = vtk.vtkFloatArray()
pdata.SetNumberOfComponents(1)
#Get the number of tuples (a component group) in the array
pdata.SetNumberOfTuples(nx*ny*nz)
#Sets the array name
pdata.SetName('pointData')

for i in range(l):
      pdata.InsertValue(int(fl[inx[0][i]][inx[1][i]][inx[2][i]]), inx[0][i]+inx[1][i]+inx[2][i])


grid.GetPointData().SetScalars(pdata)
writer = vtk.vtkXMLStructuredGridWriter()
writer.SetFileName('new_grid.vts')
#writer.SetInput(grid)
writer.SetInputData(grid)
writer.Update()
print 'end'
```

Answer (score 0):

The first argument of InsertValue requires an integer because it's the index where the value is going to be inserted. If instead of a vtkFloatArray pdata you had a numpy array called p, this would be the equivalent of your instruction:

```
pdata.InsertValue(a,b)  becomes p[a]=b
```

p[0.1] wouldn't make sense, it a must be an integer!

But I am a bit lost on the data. What do you mean that your array is  (~ 100.000 by 120)..do you have 100.000 points, and each point has a vector of 120 components? In such a case, your pdata should have 120 components, and for each point point_index you call

```
pdata.SetTuple[point_index,[v0,v1...,v119]
```

or

```
pdata.SetComponent[point_index,0,v0]
...
pdata.SetComponent[point_index,119,v119]
```

If not, are you sure that you have to access pdata based on fl values (you have to be sure that fl is int, 0 <= fl < ntuples, and that you are not going to have holes). Check if you can do the same thing that you do for cdata (btw in your code p is always equal to i, you can just use i)

It's also possible to copy a numpy array directly to vtk , see http://vtk.1045678.n5.nabble.com/vtk-to-numpy-how-to-get-a-vtk-array-tp1244891p1244895.html , but you have to be very careful with the structure of your data

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I have a big array of only flux values and then I have an array of (x,y,z) coordinates and I want to have p[x,y,z] = fl 
Your answer helped me realize that the first element of insert value is the index and not the value itself, I thought the other way and that got me confused. And I think I should get rid of the 'p' index in my code completely and instead should have (x,y,z) coordinates in insertValue in both cdata and pdata. Does it make sense that way? I guess I am supposed to use the SetTuple in that case. I am sorry, I am very new to Python and get confused.

Comment: I don't think you can use the (x,y,z) as index, just use the an ordinal number (single index) for your point -  see also the example in http://vtk.org/gitweb?p=VTK.git;a=blob;f=Examples/DataManipulation/Cxx/SGrid.cxx .  Of course, the total number of points must match the product of the dimensions of the grid - otherwise it's not a structured grid